# Java AWS s3: How to set and upload content with Md5 pre signed url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate an AWS presigned url with MD5 content. The url is generate but when I uses it to upload the content it fails with HTTP 403. error

Java code to generate the presigned URL is as below:

```
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new     GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key, httpMethod);
    byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(/*byte array*/);    
    String streamMD5 = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(resultByte));
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentMd5(streamMD5);
    s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Java code to upload data using pre signed url:

```
   HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(getImage());
        output.flush();
        assertEquals(OK, connection.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Exception: {}", e);
    }
```

I am not sure what need to be added on upload code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding following piece of code:

```
byte[] resultByte = DigestUtils.md5(/*byte array*/);    
String streamMD5 = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(resultByte));
connection.setRequestProperty("content-md5", streamMD5);
```

Make sure that MD5 code that you add while building pre signed url is same as being used to set "content-md5" header.